# How to make ScaleType.Matrix look like ScaleType.FIT_START?

Tags: java, android, imageview, touchimageview

I've tried modifying xml without success.

Currently this happens:  The image appears in the center of my TouchImageView.

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗     
║ TouchImageView                               ║
║              ╔══════════════╗                ║    
║              ║              ║    (Center)    ║    
║              ║ Actual image ║                ║    
║              ║              ║                ║    
║              ║  (Center)    ║                ║    
║              ║              ║                ║    
║              ╚══════════════╝                ║  
║                                              ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Want this: The image should appear at the top left corner of my TouchImageView.

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗     
║╔══════════════╗                              ║    
║║              ║                              ║    
║║ Actual image ║                              ║    
║║              ║                              ║    
║║              ║                              ║    
║║              ║                              ║    
║╚══════════════╝                              ║  
║                                              ║
║ TouchImageView                               ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

This is the code for the TouchImageView I'm using. 
How do I make the necessary changes so the image appears on the top left corner of the TouchImageView instead of smack in the center?

```
enter code here
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;`enter code here`
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
    Matrix matrix;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    int viewWidth, viewHeight;

    static final int CLICK = 3;

    float saveScale = 1f;

    protected float origWidth, origHeight;

    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {

        super.setClickable(true);

        this.context = context;

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

        matrix = new Matrix();

        m = new float[9];

        setImageMatrix(matrix);

        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                requestFocus();
                hideSoftKeyboard();

                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        last.set(curr);

                        start.set(last);

                        mode = DRAG;

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        if (mode == DRAG) {

                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;

                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;

                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);

                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);

                            fixTrans();

                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);

                        }

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        mode = NONE;

                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);

                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);

                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)

                            performClick();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                        mode = NONE;

                        break;

                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);

                invalidate();

                return true; // indicate event was handled

            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {

        maxScale = x;

    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            mode = ZOOM;

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

            float origScale = saveScale;

            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;

            if (saveScale > maxScale) {

                saveScale = maxScale;

                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;

            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {

                saveScale = minScale;

                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;

            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)

                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);

            else

                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();

            return true;

        }

    }

    void fixTrans() {

        matrix.getValues(m);

        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);

        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)

            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);

    }



    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {

            minTrans = 0;

            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;

        } else {

            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;

            maxTrans = 0;

        }

        if (trans < minTrans)

            return -trans + minTrans;

        if (trans > maxTrans)

            return -trans + maxTrans;

        return 0;

    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {

            return 0;

        }

        return delta;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight

                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)

            return;

        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;

        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {

            //Fit to screen.

            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)

                return;

            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;

            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;

            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image

            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);

            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);

            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;

            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;

            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;

            setImageMatrix(matrix);

        }

        fixTrans();

    }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the translation that centers the image.

```
            // Center the image

            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);

            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);

            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;

            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            // take out the translation that centers the image
            // leave all the other calculations since they are used
            // to determine origWidth and origHeight
//            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;

            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks I did something similar by setting redundantYSpace to 0. But when I zoom, the top of the image zooms out of the ImageView and I have to pan it down. If I do the same thing in a webview (which supports zoom and pan) it won't zoom out of the top border of the webview. I'm currently looking into a PhotoView library which seems to perform better and I can do FIT_START but has some additional caveats I'm trying to work through. Thanks!

Comment: Btw I just gave it a try by removing postTranslate line. The image appears at the top left and as soon as I zoom. The image gets centered again. Any ideas? it would be good if I can use this file instead of a pre-built library.

Comment: OK fixed. Also had to change the following line:
                //matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
to
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, 0);


now the problem is that if I rotate the device to landscape zoom in then zooming out the picture becomes centered on X axis :S... very annoying.

Comment: Even more annoying now is that if I rotate from portrait to landscape mode. I zoom around in landscape mode then rotate from landscape to portrait. The image goes off screen in the portrait setting when zoomed out fully.

Answer (score 0):

To support the imageView scaleType (`ScaleType.FIT_START` and `ScaleType.FIT_XY`), the following code can be modified in TouchImageView class:

1. For `ScaleType.FIT_START`, remove the following line:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    // matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
    }
```

2. For `ScaleType.FIT_XY`, replace the following line:

```
      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

      // matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, mViewWidth / 2,
      //                        mViewHeight / 2);

      //Replace this line with: 
      matrix.setScale(scaleX,scaleY);
      }
```